# Update PostgreSQL database with daily stock prices in Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, stock

So I found a great script over at [QuantState](http://www.quantstart.com/articles/Securities-Master-Database-with-MySQL-and-Python) that had a great walk-through on setting up my own securities database and loading in historical pricing information. However, I'm not trying to modify the script so that I can run it daily and have the latest stock quotes added.

I adjusted the initial data load to just download 1 week worth of historicals, but I've been having issues with writing the SQL statement to see if the row exists already before adding. Can anyone help me out with this. Here's what I have so far:

```
def insert_daily_data_into_db(data_vendor_id, symbol_id, daily_data):
  """Takes a list of tuples of daily data and adds it to the
   database. Appends the vendor ID and symbol ID to the data.

  daily_data: List of tuples of the OHLC data (with 
  adj_close and volume)"""

  # Create the time now
  now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

  # Amend the data to include the vendor ID and symbol ID
  daily_data = [(data_vendor_id, symbol_id, d[0], now, now,
    d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5], d[6]) for d in daily_data]

  # Create the insert strings
  column_str = """data_vendor_id, symbol_id, price_date, created_date, 
          last_updated_date, open_price, high_price, low_price, 
          close_price, volume, adj_close_price"""
  insert_str = ("%s, " * 11)[:-2]
  final_str = "INSERT INTO daily_price (%s) VALUES (%s) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM daily_price WHERE symbol_id = symbol_id AND price_date = insert_str[2])" % (column_str, insert_str)

  # Using the postgre connection, carry out an INSERT INTO for every symbol
  with con: 
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.executemany(final_str, daily_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some notes regarding your code above:

It's generally easier to defer to `now()` in pure *SQL* than to try in *Python* whenever possible. It avoids lots of potential pitfalls with timezones, library differences, etc.

If you construct a *list* of columns, you can dynamically generate a string of `%s`'s based on its size, and don't need to hardcode the length into a repeated string with is then  sliced.

Since it appears that `insert_daily_data_into_db` is meant to be called from within a loop on a per-stock basis, I don't believe you want to use `executemany` here, which would require a *list* of *tuples* and is very different semantically.

You were comparing symbol_id to itself in the sub `select`, instead of a particular value (which would mean it's always true).

To prevent possible *SQL Injection*, you should always interpolate values in the `WHERE` clause, including sub `select`s.

**Note:** I'm assuming that you're using *psycopg2* to access *Postgres*, and that the primary key for the table is a tuple of `(symbol_id, price_date)`. If not, the code below would need to be tweaked at least a bit.

With those points in mind, try something like this (untested, since I don't have your data, db, etc. but it is syntactically valid Python):

```
def insert_daily_data_into_db(data_vendor_id, symbol_id, daily_data):
    """Takes a list of tuples of daily data and adds it to the
    database. Appends the vendor ID and symbol ID to the data.

    daily_data: List of tuples of the OHLC data (with
    adj_close and volume)"""


    column_list = ["data_vendor_id", "symbol_id", "price_date", "created_date",
                    "last_updated_date", "open_price", "high_price", "low_price",
                    "close_price", "volume", "adj_close_price"]

    insert_list = ['%s'] * len(column_str)

    values_tuple = (data_vendor_id, symbol_id, daily_data[0], 'now()', 'now()', daily_data[1],
                    daily_data[2], daily_data[3], daily_data[4], daily_data[5], daily_data[6])

    final_str = """INSERT INTO daily_price ({0})
                     VALUES ({1})
                     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                       FROM daily_price
                                       WHERE symbol_id = %s
                                         AND price_date = %s)""".format(', '.join(column_list), ', '.join(insert_list))

    # Using the postgre connection, carry out an INSERT INTO for every symbol
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(final_str, values_tuple, values_tuple[1], values_tuple[2])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. I'm running into a situation where I keep getting this error - `LINE 1: INSERT INTO daily_price ({['data_vendor_id', 'symbol_id', 'p...` Here's how I changed the SQL code: `    final_str = """INSERT INTO daily_price (%s)
                     VALUES (%s)
                     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                       FROM daily_price
                                       WHERE symbol_id = %s
                                         AND price_date = %s)""" % (column_list, values_tuple, values_tuple[1], values_tuple[2])`

Comment: Sure, no problem. What's the whole error? It looks like your column list is wrapped in a `dict`, which would lead to an error in this case.

Comment: Here's the full error - `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "retrievePrices-daily.py", line 89, in <module>
    insert_daily_data_into_db('1', t[0], yf_data)
  File "retrievePrices-daily.py", line 79, in insert_daily_data_into_db
    cur.execute(final_str, values_tuple)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: INSERT INTO daily_price (['data_vendor_id', 'symbol_id', 'pr...`

Comment: That looks like a list wrapped in a tuple, which would lead to the syntax error... Are you defining `column_list` as I defined it in my code snippet?

Comment: I am - I copied and pasted your code: `    column_list = ["data_vendor_id", "symbol_id", "price_date", "created_date",
                    "last_updated_date", "open_price", "high_price", "low_price",
                    "close_price", "volume", "adj_close_price"]`

Comment: If you use *pdb* to set a breakpoint, what's your value of `final_str` right before the `cur.execute` call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59556/discussion-between-ken-hampson-and-jdgd).

Comment: Hey @Ken Hampson, thanks for all the help - finally got it working using the following: `final_str = "INSERT INTO daily_price (%s) SELECT %s WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM daily_price WHERE symbol_id = '%s' AND price_date = '%s')" % (column_str, insert_str, daily_data_new[1], daily_data_new[2])
`